# Am I looking at GIT branches in GIT clients wrong?

Tags: git, user-interface, branch

When I work with GIT branches my "mental model" of any given branch is that it is a path which breaks out from the branch which I base that branch on. Let's assume I do the following :

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b feature/1
touch README.md
git add --all
git commit -m "Added README.md"
git push -u origin feature/1
git checkout develop
git merge feature/1
git push
```

Now, I would expect a git GUI to visualise this by drawing a `develop` branch as a separate path. Then, from the `develop` branch path I would expect to see a `feature/1` branch path break out from the `develop` branch path. I would then expect to see the two paths go alongside each other, until i merge `feature/1` into develop. At this point I would expect to see the `feature/1` branch path merge back into the `develop` branch path.

[image]

However, when I only work at a single branch at any given time (in addition to the develop and master branch which are always there) - this is not what happens. If I begin work on a new branch, finish the branch and merge it back into develop, it all seems to take place on the same "path". However, when I work on two branches at the same time it seems that one of the branches breaks out on its own path. However, the first branch is just visualised as a continuation of the develop branch.

[image]

I find it confusing that only one of the branches are visually represented with its own path, while the other is just represented as a direct continuation of the develop branch. Am I getting this wrong - or thinking about branches wrong? I just want to get a clear and consistent view of when I broke a new branch out of develop and when i merged it back in again. In my opinion, having a separate path for every branch created would make this easier to get.

[image]

Is there a GIT client out there which does this? Or do I need to look at this differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "problem" is, that you are not aware of fast-forward merges. If there is nothing to merge, meaning you didn't change anything on develop between the point where you branched off and merge back, you do a fast-forward merge by default that just makes `develop` point to the same commit as `feature/1`. If you want to have the history with different paths preserved, you can use the `--no-ff` option of `merge` which will create a merge commit even if there is nothing to merge actually. Then any Git client will show you the image you expect. If you don't do it, no Git client can show it to you as that is not how the history looks like.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing here is the difference between [*fast-forward merges*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_fast_forward_merge) and [*true merges*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_true_merge).

In Git, merging a branch into another doesn't always result in a [*merge commit*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merging); if no new commits were made on the destination branch since the *branching point*, Git will simply move the source branch forward so that it points to the same commit as the destination branch.

Consider this example:

```
A - B - C (master)
     \        
      E - F (feature)
```

Here, the branching point of the `feature` branch is commit `B`. Since then, commit `C` was made on the `master` branch. If you were to merge `feature` into `master`, Git would notice that the branching point is no longer the latest commit in `master`, hence it would have to *tie* the two lines of history together (what you call "*paths*") by creating a *merge commit*, that is a commit that has more than one parent:

```
A - B - C - M (master)
     \     /   
      E - F (feature)
```

However, if no new commits happened on `master` since the branching point, Git would simply move the `master` branch forward to point to the same commit as `feature`. This is called a [*fast-forward* merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddeffastforwardafast-forward):

> **fast-forward**
>   A fast-forward is a special type of merge where you have a revision and you are "merging" another branch's changes that
>   happen to be a descendant of what you have. In such a case, you do not
>   make a new merge commit but instead just update to his revision.

So, given this scenario:

```
A - B (master)
     \        
      E - F (feature)
```

Merging `feature` into `master` would simply result in:

```
A - B - E - F (master, feature)
```

If you want to force Git to create a merge commit even if it would do a *fast-forward* merge, you can add the [`--no-ff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---no-ff) option of [`git-merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge). So doing this:

```
git merge feature --no-ff
```

Would result in:

```
A - B - M (master)
     \   \   
      E - F (feature)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: Git 2.33 (Q3 2021) clarifies the description of "`fast-forward`" in the glossary:

See [commit e22f2da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e22f2daed0fde4595696e09c6802a1ecd5e0c527) (19 May 2021) by [Reuven Y (`robi-y`)](https://github.com/robi-y).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7f06d94](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f06d94e7292a555ac83ba2c26ea0b5973d94797), 10 Jun 2021)</sup>

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e22f2daed0fde4595696e09c6802a1ecd5e0c527): improve fast-forward in glossary content
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Reuven Yagel</sup>

> The text was somewhat confusing between the revision itself and the author.

`glossary-content` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e22f2daed0fde4595696e09c6802a1ecd5e0c527/Documentation/glossary-content.txt#L149-L150):

> > ### fast-forward:
> >
> > A fast-forward is a special type of merge, where you have a revision and you are "merging" another branch's changes that happen to be a descendant of what you have.
>
> In such a case, you do not make a new  merge commit, but instead just **update your branch to point at the same revision as the branch you are merging**.